# Using jquery to animate a div button into a bigger menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu button that when you click it it becomes bigger and it has menu items in it using jquery but for some reason it just disappears here is the jquery i'm using for it here is the page i'm having trouble on

billischill.ddns.net/testroom.php

```
$(document).on("click", "#addtomsg", function(){
    $('#addtomsg').addClass('open');
})
```

and here are my styles

```
#addtomsg.open{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
   }
#addtomsg p{
    margin-top:3px;
   }
#addtomsg{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-left:30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
    width: 40px;
    height:20px;
    background:#006666;
   }
```

and here is my html

```
</div>

<form name="message" id="fixedinput"action="">
<div name="addtomsg" id="addtomsg">
  <center>
  <p>+<p>
  </center>
</div>
    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="73"class="textinpt" />
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" class="submit2"/>
</form>
</div>
```

can someone please help me

Comment: post your html here

Comment: Works for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/c7emjgjk/

Comment: Works fine. Are you getting any errores in console?

Comment: I'm sorry it just doesnt seem to work on my site

Comment: No i am not getting any errors... and could i also maybe make it toggleable

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly isolated like that. If you have no errors on console, and you're importing jQuery correctly, then we can't really tell what's wrong unless you share the whole thing.

If you want to make it *toggleable* as you've said on a comment, please replace your `addClass` with `toggleClass` and it will give you the result you want.

```
$(document).on("click", "#addtomsg", function(){
    $('#addtomsg').toggleClass('open');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#addtomsg").click(function(){   
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
#addtomsg.open{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
   }
#addtomsg p{
    margin-top:3px;
   }
#addtomsg{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-left:30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
    width: 40px;
    height:20px;
    background:#006666;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="message" id="fixedinput"action="">
<div name="addtomsg" id="addtomsg">
  <center>
  <p>+<p>
  </center>
</div>
  <br>
  <br>
    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="73"class="textinpt" />
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" class="submit2"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this may help

```
 <script>
    $(document).on("click", "#addtomsg", function(){
        $('#addtomsg').addClass('open');
    })
    </script>
<style>
#addtomsg.open{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
   }
#addtomsg p{
    margin-top:3px;
   }
#addtomsg{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin-left:30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
    width: 40px;
    height:20px;
    background:#006666;
   }
</style>

    <div id="addtomsg">
      hi
    </div>
```

I'm not the best at jquery still learning but it's something.